# Delayed Job: Configure run_at and max_attempts for a specific job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I need to overwrite the `Delayed::Worker.max_attempts` for one specific job, which I want to retry a lot of times. Also, I don't want the next scheduled time to be determined exponentially (From the docs: 5 seconds + N ** 4, where N is the number of retries).

I don't want to overwrite the `Delayed::Worker` settings, and affect other jobs.

My job is already a custom job (I handle errors in a certain way), so that might be helpful. Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out by looking through `delayed_job` source code. This is not documented anywhere in their docs.

Here's what I did:

```
class MyCustomJob < Struct.new(:param1, :param2)
  def perform
    # do something
  end
  
  # attempts and time params are required by delayed_job
  def reschedule_at(time, attempts)
    30.seconds.from_now
  end

  def max_attempts
    50
  end
end
```

Then run it wherever you need to by using `enqueue`, like this:

```rb
Delayed::Job.enqueue( MyCustomJob.new( param1, param2 ) )
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: arguments in ```reschedule_at``` should be switched: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/95deddc99af84e652dd865a292e959db4b0a1179/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb#L133

Comment: I have one doubt, how do we check if an attempt to perform a task is actually failing?

Comment: FYI, this method is now described clearly in the docs here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs You were ahead of the game!