# Adding max attempt for a single delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am trying to add max_attempt(if that fails) for a single delayed job

```
@user.delay(attempts: 2).send_an_email
```

and this shows attempts column in delayed job is missing

But  could do that for the whole application with adding a delayed_job_config file in the initializer

```
# config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
  Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 3
  Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
```

Is there anyway to add it for single delayed job?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16227229/10347572 should be what you're looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delayed Job: Configure run\_at and max\_attempts for a specific job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226922/delayed-job-configure-run-at-and-max-attempts-for-a-specific-job)

Comment: Thanks, but I am sure about where to create the class, is it under lib folder

Answer (score 1):

#### You have to use a Custom Job.

You have to create a custom job in order to override the `max_attempts`.

As you can see in the README [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#parameters), the only params that the `.delay` method take are:

- `priority`
- `run_at`
- `queue`

And if you think about it, a value for `max_attempts` is not stored in the `delayed_jobs` table, only the `attempts` are stored, so there's no way for it to be persisted.

The only way to do it is to create a custom job that gets re-instantiated when the delayed job worker processes the job. It then reads the value from the `max_attempts` method and uses that to determine if the current `attempts` in the table record equals or exceeds the `max_attempts` value.

In your case, the simplest way to do it would be something like this:

```rb
# Inside your user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  SendAnEmailJob = Struct.new( :user ) do 
  
    def perform
      user.send_an_email
    end

    def queue_name
      "email"
    end

    def max_attempts
      2
    end

  end

end
```

Then run it wherever you need to by using `enqueue`, like this:

```rb
Delayed::Job.enqueue( User::SendAnEmailJob.new( user ) )
```